# Updating pages in SMW

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I am a total newbie with SMW, and I've inherited a system that no one knows any details about.

I have a few questions:

How can I find out what and where the database behind the SMW is? I would think there is a config file somewhere, but I can't find it.

When I look at a page with browsebysubject I see a type associated with the data, e.g.:

```
{u'property': u'HasSide', u'dataitem': [{u'item': u'Left', u'type': 2}]}
{u'property': u'HasReferenceDataset', u'dataitem': [{u'item':
u'RefData, u'type': 9}]}
```

What do these types mean?

I have been asked to edit 1000's of pages to remove 2 fields and add a new field. To do this with the API would I get the data with browsebysubject and modify that dict? But then how would I write that back?

Or would I get the raw data with index.php?action=raw, modify that, and then write it back with edit (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit).

I tried the latter and that caused the data for the 2 fields I want to remove to disappear, but the field headers did not, and my new field is not shown. Then I though I had to change the form, and I did that, but the form changes are not reflected in the page. I think there has to be some linkage between the fields on the form and some columns or something in the database. I don't think I can just put in any free form tag and have it work.

Any help or direction at all that anyone can give me will be greatly appreciated.